# How to return data in specific format from Python Flask API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I am writing a get API using python flask.
This API is for a FAQ webpage in which there are multiple question and answers which are divided section wise.

### Webpage Example: How Webpage section looks for FAQ

```
**Section 1**
    Question : Question 1 for section1?
    Answer : Answer 1 for section 1.
    
    Question : Question 2 for section1?
    Answer : Answer 2 for section1.

**Section 2**
    Question : Question 1 for section2?
    Answer : Answer 1 for section 1.
    
    Question : Question 2 for section2?
    Answer : Answer 2 for section1.
```

I have written this python API code

```
@app.route('/getProductFaqs')
def productfaqs():
    try:
        conn = mysql.connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute("SELECT id, product_name, product_question, product_answer FROM questionFAQ")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        resp = jsonify(rows)
        resp.status_code = 200
        return resp
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
```

which returns data in this format

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "product_answer": "answer product 1",
    "product_name": "product 1",
    "product_question": "What is product 1?"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "product_answer": "answer product 2",
    "product_name": "product 2",
    "product_question": "What is product 2?"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "product_answer": "answer product 3",
    "product_name": "product 3",
    "product_question": "What is product 3?"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "product_answer": "answer product 4",
    "product_name": "product 4",
    "product_question": "What is product 4?"
  }
]
```

However my requirement for API response is in this format

```
[
  {
    productid: 1[
      {
        Question: question1?
        Answer: answer1.
      },
      {
        Question: question2?
        Answer: Answer2.
      }
    ]
  },
 {
    productid: 2[
      {
        Question: question1?
        Answer: answer1.
      },
      {
        Question: question2?
        Answer: Answer2.
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Can please someone help me out with this formatting of response.
Thankyou in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

my friend. I have some tips for you.
First of all, you should not use a database connection like this.
This way, you can not easily use it in other parts of your program.
Second, It's usually better to use an ORM like Sqlalchemy integrated with Flask. It will help you satisfy also the first problem.

And for your question, you should parse the result of your query, tailor it to fulfill your requirements, and store it in a dictionary so that you can then return it as a JSON object.